# Where do I update my constraint before the view is on screen?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I need to update some `NSLayoutConstraints` before the view comes on screen depending on the device's screen size.

What I want to do is that this update becomes invisible to the user's eyes. 
And I do not know where I can do that because : 
- if I do this in :

`- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`

of my `UIViewController` it is called twice so i make twice the calculation on my constraint and I do not want to set a bool or a counter... 
- if I do this in :

`- (void)viewDidLoad`

it does not work because I calculate my constrain's value based on the view of the view controller which is 0 height at this moment.

I see that there are a lot of methods for auto layout (`setNeedsUpdate` ...) 
and if someone could tell me the best way to achieve an update of the constraints only once in the viewController lifeCycle that would be great.

Thanks for any help! (N.B: the auto-layout concept is new to me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding `updateViewConstraints` on your view controller. (Don't forget to call super ;) )

[See Apple docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/updateViewConstraints)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I'll check the doc but may be you can tell if it also work on UIView ?

Comment: Yep - you can also do it directly on a UIView by overriding `updateConstraints`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/updateConstraints

Comment: John, one last thing, i could find that in the doc it looks like i do need to call layoutIfNeeded why ?

Comment: If constraints need to be added or removed, you should call setNeedsUpdateConstraints - this will flag to the layout system that an update is required and it will call your updateConstraints method on the next layout pass, which should then trigger layoutIfNeeded to the affected views.  If you call layoutIfNeeded directly, the layout system will update subviews immediately, rather than on the next layout pass - sometime you might need to do this e.g. if you need to get the updated frame for a view to perform some other layout-based calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can create the outlet of your height constraint from storyboard.

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightForYourView;

& in viewDidLoad write the following code which will automatically change the size

```
//if you want to change the size as per device check device type in my case it iphone6 
if (IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
        self.heightForYourView.constant=250;//height you want
    }
```